# Sys.person is not available in DialogFlow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

DialogFlowCX does not provide sys.person.
Neither last_name nor given-name is provided.
Is sys.person obsolete?
I am using Japanese.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3I6b.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the language used, but with the agent's region and data residency compliance.

For U.S. regions, **Data residency compliant** setting defaults to `false`, and can be changed to `true`. For other regions, the setting is set to `true`, and it cannot be changed.

Some system entity types are not data residency compliant yet. If you need compliance for these entities, consider using `@sys.any` until support is added. For example, where you would normally use `@sys.person`, create two form parameters, `given-name` and `family-name`, with a `@sys.any` entity type. The agent can prompt for these values individually when form filling.